# How are Expiry dates on UK passports written?

Tags: uk, passports

In my British Passport the expiry date is given as 08APR meaning 8th April. It is followed by AVR24 for year of expiry. What does the AVR24 stand for?

Comment: any chance you're seeing APR/AVR followed by 24? The French for April is Avril, and your passport might expire in 2024.

Answer (score 15):

They are written in the following format:

> Day English-Month /French-Month Year

So for example:

> 01 Aug /Aout 25

For 1st August 2025.

Your date is simply 8th April 2024.

Comment: I've known this almost my entire life and it _still_ takes me a few moments to parse, every time. ^_^

Comment: Yeah, I have exactly the same problem!